# Using Swift 3 'self.present' to present a new View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, segue

I am currently making an app in which I want to be able to enter the players of a game on the first View Controller, and for the button to run through a series of condition-checks. If all conditions are met, I want it to then take the User to the next View Controller.

My issue is that I am not entirely sure how to go about presenting the next View Controller. Currently I am trying to use the 'self.present' function to go about it, but I am struggling to find how to get it to work in Swift 3.

Any help as to how to do this, or advice on any alternative options to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: My Storyboard]

[image: Class for the View Controller in the Attributes inspector.]

The if/else statements that trigger on button press:

```
if meTextField.text == "" {

        if errLabelNotBlank == false {

            errorLabel.isHidden = false
            errorLabel.text = "You must be playing!"
            errLabelNotBlank = true

        }

    } else if playersDict.count < 2 {

        errorLabel.isHidden = false
        errorLabel.text = "You need at least 2 players!"
        errLabelNotBlank = true

    } else {

        //Code to present the next VC here

    }
```

Comment: `but I am struggling to find how to get it to work in Swift 3.` What exactly is the issue?  I don't see you call `present` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't call it in my code as of currently. The main issue when I try to call that is that it says that the name of the View Controller I type in, ConfirmPlayersVC, is an unresolved identifier. I presume I'm entering it incorrectly, but I just don't know how I specify the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a segue between the two view controllers. Drag and drop from the view controllers itself (Not the enter button). Make it a "Present Modally" type.

[image: add segue]

Once thats done, click on the segue thing and click the attributes inspector (the arrow). Change the identifier to whatever you want like "ShowScanner" in this example.
[image: scanner]

Put this code inside where you want to change views.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowScanner", sender: self)
```